# Lambda function timelimit per execution(back4app/Container)

Tags: docker, lambda, back4app

I have a container app with a http server in it.
Request to certain route takes quite a long time(up to 2 minutes) per execution, yea...
Also Ive noticed that back4app is using AWS services under the hood, since Im getting error with AWS Cloudfront-like output:

504 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)

Request ID: `1kYIL7KH9foQUmol07rFfmrfVu0HEcCg01emcWfeiah6mLteXjKpFQ==`

Also aws lambda provides a "Timelimit per execution" configuration. By default it is set to 3sec.

My question is there such timelimit in back4app and is there a way to extend it?

I tried to find some details in FAQ and Troubleshooting back4app docs. But found nothing so far.

I expect to extend Timelimit per execution for my cloudfunction.

Many thanks :)

Comment: I think that you might contact their team, so, they will be able to ask for additional details and see how they can help you with that.